# Javascript + Filter object of values

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, mapreduce

I have the object with values. I trying to filter based on values.

```
var data = {
  "map": {
    "0": ["abcd"],
    "1": ["efgh"],
    "2": ["xyz"],
  }
}
```

In above object I am trying to filter xyz which are have in array values.

Expecting output:

```
 { '0': [ 'xyz' ] }
```

I done the code but I am not sure it's efficient way. Can someone help me this.

```js
const  data = {
  "map": {
    "0": ["abcd"],
    "1": ["efgh"],
    "2": ["xyz"],
    "3": ["abcd", "xyz"],
  }
}

const filtered = Object.keys(data.map)
  .filter((key) => {
    return data.map[key].includes('xyz');
  })
  .reduce((obj, key, cIndex) => {
    obj[cIndex] = data.map[key];
    return obj;
  }, {});
  
  console.log('filtered', filtered);
```

Comment: Should I assume the input will always be a dictionary whose keys are integers from `0` to `n`, and the order should also be kept in output?

Comment: yes. the output order always should start from 0

Answer (score 1):

### Avoid use dictionary when you need `Array`

I'm not sure why you would prefer to store your Array-like data in a dictionary. I would suggest use a real Array if you need an Array.

### Order of `Object.keys`

You may read more details about the order of `Object.keys` return values from this post: [Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30919039/2045384) The order of `Object.keys` is defined in ES2020. It may not work as you want in older environments.

Anyway, relay on the order of `Object.keys` don't seems to be a good idea to me. You may always sort the keys after `Object.keys` if you want though.

### Use `Object.assign` to convert to / from `Array`

When you need an Array, use an Array. You can try `Object.assign` which convert your dictionary into Array and vice versa. (But this only applied to "when you cannot change the interface due to any reason").

```javascript
function filterData(data, value) {
    const arrayData = Object.assign([], data.map);
    const filteredArrayData = arrayData.filter(list => list.includes(value));
    const result = Object.assign({}, filteredArrayData);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I add this in typescript I am getting error in includes.. Error details (Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339))

Comment: @RSKMR Maybe you want to change your question to TypeScript?

Comment: Thanks @tsh for contributing this great answer - I hope to see more from you in future!

Comment: @RSKMR TypeScript seems not smart enough to know types correctly. So [some internal variables may help](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBvAUDGAiAWwQAc8AuTHXfABnJgG08EAjYOPAXQBorc8AjPSYBTAGYBzABZde1fACZheAB4BPAF6y++AMzLW7PN3zqtPKgF8s1rGICuYYFACW4GGJcAbKCIBOACJICAAUiMgUGDBExJGMANYiahRg9gQs-pwU0H4uYBIMnDCWxSYAbghe9iLZULn5AJSU8qCQsAh+fghqQREwOXkFnIVoMADyLABWIs4AdAgQEC4SYCGFJuEIszENANw6rdAe3r5+InAAgp3dvSjoHV09wbOePv4hXi5HqAB8MJ-QWZ5YBVOAiCAhCpVEQNPYHcBHM4Qew+OIMRLJGCpdKZWr1IbFUYTaZzBZLFYhDCWEyvU7nK6PW5w+RnKD2PxgGBIlFQfa2Q4gLwiWZeEASEK0-y3MLBEwAcjMcth+yAA).

Answer (score 0):

### Review

- the whole filter chain could be on basis of `value` instead of `key` from `data` since there's no real use of key here

#### `filter` part

- technically your approach is perfect, just that it could be concise/readable
- you can simplify the `filter` as in below snippet, simply because readability is one of the TOP priority of a good code IMHO

#### `map` part

- instead of juggling the same `object` inside `reduce` between all elements we can simply get the required objects out of it.
- one other major thing is that `reduce` as the name suggests is for when you wish to *reduce* **N** elements into exactly **1** element by some logic, which clearly isn't the case here & thus i think `map` should be preferred.
- we can use `map` here since at the end we want an `array` of `object`s, so here we can return `object` for **each** key which at end gets **collected as** `array`
- apart from these the redability point again applies here as well, since this can also be simplified very much, refer the snippet to get an idea
- quoting a point from Mozilla's doc on `reduce`

> The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in single output value.

### Alternate approach

```js
const  data = {
  "map": {
    "0": ["abcd"],
    "1": ["efgh"],
    "2": ["xyz"],
    "3": ["abcd", "xyz"],
  }
}

const filtered = Object.values(data.map)
  .filter(value => value.includes('xyz'))
   // the () after the "=>" are used to wrap returned result into object
   // the [i] inside ({..}) is used for setting the key dynamically
  .map((value, i) => ({[i]: value}));
  
console.log('filtered', filtered);
```

- The data structure seems to be object representation of `array`, so if possible prefer `2D array` over `object` with 0 based keys, this would make things more simple

PS: answer is updated after useful suggestions of @Toby Speight & @Graipher in comments

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].

Comment: @TobySpeight Well, there is some review here, it is just hidden in the comments in the code. This would be a lot better answer if you pulled it out of the comments and put it into text, Harsh Gundecha.

Comment: I easily miss comments in the code; I too prefer descriptive text outside of the code block.  That's easier to tell apart from a review focusing on the commenting of the code, for one thing.